# Do circular arrays override current number if you try to enque in a full array?

Tags: java, arrays

Do circular arrays override if you try to enqueue a number over an already filled index?

For example, say I have a circular array of 8 integers, only 5 indexes have numbers stored. 2 is the front and 6 is the back. If I enqueue 4 numbers, when it fills up to index 1, that is only 3 numbers inserted and I still have one number left to insert but there is no room because index 2 is already filled. Does my last number I am enqueing override index 2 or is the number irrelevant and the back stays at index 1, front at index 2?

Hope that makes sense, my gut tells me that if I have another number to enqueue it won't override the current numbers, but I need reassurance.

Comment: you are going to have to give more info (aka you need to specify what language you are using and what context)

Comment: Woops, sorry forgot to mention. Added it to the above post. Doing this in Java.

Comment: Are you writing your own?  Or using Guava, Apache Commons, or the standard Java Collections Library?

Comment: Just the standard Java Collections Library

Comment: There is no circular array built in to the standard Java 7 collections library.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer is that it depends on the implementation.  You can build your own circular array that checks the length and refuses to insert when full (either by throwing an exception or returning an error status code), and you can build one that happily overwrites.  You can even build one that blocks the current thread when trying to insert into a full queue, unblocking it only when another thread removes an element.

There is no real "standard" here, though if you are using a pre-existing library the check its documentation.

The Java programming language for example, does not have circular arrays in its standard library.  Again, you are free to write one either way.  Various implementations of the `java.util.Queue` interface may have circular arrays underneath the hood, but you won't see them exposed as such.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the question is not very specific here, so I am a little confused. I will just add a note in with my answer that it depends on the implementation. Thank you for your input. :)